# How to launch & use separate browser for each test method inside a class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have the below scenario

All the 3 tests run, but they are sharing only 1 browser. I have all the common methods for all the clicks etc in a Base class.

I want each of the test method -method1/2/3 to launch different browser & work,
Can somebody help?

```
Class A extends BaseTest{
@BeforeMethod(){
initDriver();// it does setdriver & getDriver is used across
}
public void doStuff(){
...
}
@Test
public void method1(){
doStuff()
}
@Test
public void method2(){
doStuff()
}
@Test
public void method3(){
doStuff()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestNG.xml to parameterized and control your execution as below. Here we ahve created 3 different tests , each one of them is parameterized with browser type variable and running one of your @test method.

**TestNG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="TestChrome">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>   
      <class name ="<Full path to your Test class>" /> 
         <methods>
            <include name="method1" />
         </methods>
    </classes>
  </test> 

<test name="TestForefox">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>   
      <class name ="<Full path to your Test class>" /> 
         <methods>
            <include name="method2" />
         </methods>
    </classes>
  </test> 

<test name="TestIE">
    <parameter name="browser" value="edge"/>
    <classes>   
      <class name ="<Full path to your Test class>" /> 
         <methods>
            <include name="method3" />
         </methods>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Get the browser type parameter in your @BeforeMethod.

```
@Parameters ({"browser"})
@BeforeMethod(){
initDriver(browser);/* it does setdriver & getDriver is used across. Passing browser name 
                     to initDriver method.*/
}
```

Now in initDriver() method ( wherever you have implemented it), set driver based on your browser type. Something similar to below:

```
public void initDriver(String browser) throws Exception{
        
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ".\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
                else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge")){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",".\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
                    driver = new EdgeDriver();
                }
        else{
            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.window().maximize();
    }
```

**Note:** Using include/exclude tag in TestNg.xml file you can run/ignore any @Test methods inside a test.